# is it possible to write in ternary?

Tags: php, ternary

```
//if more than one attribute is being added
if (is_array($data[0])) 
{
    $datas = $data;    
}
//if only one attribute is being added
else
{
    $datas[0] = $data;
}
```

I was wondering if the above code can be written in ternary in one line

Comment: You could write it as a one line without a ternary. Just delete all newline characters. PHP doesn't require them at all anyway.

Comment: @Gherman that is a very poor recommendation

Comment: @WesleySmith This is not a recommendation at all. I think the question is not very practical to begin with but more about language gramar and its possibilities. If you think about it most JavaScript minifiers do exactly that besides many other things.

Comment: If a question is directly asking if something, that you perceive as bad, is possible it doesn't creat grounds for closing it. Which rules of SO do you think are broken here?

Answer (score 7):

Technically, yes:

```
is_array($data[0]) ? $datas = $data : $datas[0] = $data;
```

But **don't**.

Ternary operators are designed to express the operation:

```
something = condition ? value : other-value
```

Using them for:

```
condition ? operation : other-operation
```

… is confusing at best.

If you have an `if/else` situation then use `if/else` statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$datas = is_array($data[0])? $data : [$data];
```

Comment: `is_array($data[0])`